# Maximum size of clipboard in current browsers

Tags: javascript, browser

Are there browser related limits to the size of a text that can be pasted **from** clipboard?  Do these limits differ for different browsers (e.g. IE, Chrome, Firefox)? In our company there exists some anecdotal knowledge about limits, but doing some research on google did not really lead me to reliable facts.

The text will be copied to the clipboard by external programs (e.g. Microsoft Excel). Therefore I am only interested in pasting from the clipboard and not in copying to the clipboard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most data is copied as a reference rather than the data itself so you can copy most anything any size. Text though is actually copied.

For 32-bit applications can allocate blocks up to 2 GB in size or up to the amount of virtual memory the PC has, whichever is less.

It does not depend on browser or windows clipboard.

Comment: I do not know what the limits _are,_ but you absolutely cannot copy the full text of [the HSTS preload list](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/net/+/master/http/transport_security_state_static.json) in Chrome 60 on my 16GB RAM system. The page markup is ~31MB, if I understand `curl | wc` correctly.